# A Corollary of Normal Subgroup Test

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a corollary of the Normal Subgroup Test in Nicholson's *An Introduction to Abstract Algebra*.

> **Corollary.** If $G=\langle X\rangle$, 
>   a subgroup $H$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$ for all $x\in X$. 
>   In particular, 
>   $\langle a\rangle\lhd G$ if and only if $gag^{-1}\in \langle a\rangle$ for all $g\in G$.

We have learnt a similar theorem:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H=\langle S\rangle$ a subgroup of $G$. 
>   Then $H$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $gsg^{-1}\in H$ for all $s\in S$ and $g\in G$.

**My Question:** The corollary seems to be true but I can't prove it. 
Do we have $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H\Rightarrow x^{-1}Hx\subseteq H$? (Note that $X$ is just only a subset.)
If it is false, I also can't find a counterexample.

Comment: The “theorem” is wrong as stated. You need $gsg^{-1}\in H$, not $gsg\in H$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If $G$ is the Baumslag-Solitar group $G = \mathrm{BS}(1,2) = \langle a,b : bab^{-1} = a^2 \rangle$, then $H = \langle a \rangle$ satisfies $a H a^{-1}  = H \subset H$ and $b H b^{-1}  = \langle a^2 \rangle \subset H$. However, $H$ is not normal, since $b^{-1} H b \not\subset H$. In particular, $x H x^{-1} \subseteq H$ does not always imply that $x^{-1} H x \subseteq H$. So the corollary is only true (in general) if one uses the convention that generating sets $\langle X \rangle$ must be symmetric (i.e. $x \in X \rightarrow x^{-1} \in X$).

Comment: OTOH, if $G$ is finite, then  $x H x^{-1} \subseteq H$  implies that $x H x^{-1} = H$ and then $H = x^{-1} H x$.

Comment: @user670344 Excellent! How did you come up with this counterexample? Would you like to post this comment as an answer?

Comment: If $H$ is finite, then $xHx^{-1}$ and $H$ have the same cardinality and thus an inclusion implies an equality. So any counterexample must have $H$ infinite, and contain a subgroup $H' = xHx^{-1} \subset H$ which is isomorphic to $H$ but strictly contained in $H$. The easiest example of such a pair of groups is $2 \mathbf{Z} \subset \mathbf{Z}$. So now you want a group with $\mathbf{Z}$ as a subgroup and such that conjugation by some element sends $1$ to $2$. So the example writes itself.

Comment: I don't answer questions from users with such a low rate of answer acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

For $h\in H$ and $x_1,x_2\in X$, we have

$$(x_1x_2)h(x_1x_2)^{-1} = x_1(x_2hx_2^{-1})x_1^{-1}.$$

If $xhx^{-1}\in H$ for all $x\in X$, prove that the above element is in $H$ then generalize this pattern to show that $ghg^{-1}\in H$ for all $g\in G$.

Comment: Hello. There is a counterexample in the comment. The point is $x^{-1}$ may not be in $X$. The hypothesis only says $xhx^{-1}\in H$ for all "$x\in X$''.

Comment: @bfhaha It’s true if you allow that possibility. As also stated in that comment, the convention for generating sets is that they are closed under taking inverses. If you are not following that convention, you should edit your post to give your definition of a subgroup generated by a set.